# Tomcat 5.5: "Exception processing JAR at resource path" leads to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: tomcat, server-crashes, tomcat5.5, outofmemoryerror, permgen

We have an old server running Tomcat 5.5.

Yesterday we deployed a war file, and then it started to crash.

Looking at catalina.date.log I found some java.util.zip.ZipException and then java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. I think it's resulting in memory leak that crashes Tomcat when there's no more memory to feed it.

3 files are involved:

- `/var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-es.jar`
- `/var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-compiler-jdt.jar`
- `/var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-factory-dbcp.jar`

They are all in their places and aren't corrupted. Of course the `._` is the first suspect of causing the error. The problem is that these files aren't referenced anywhere in application, even more a i18n-es one, because it has no i18n feature and no spanish config in it and, ALAIK, neither in Tomcat.

Upgrading Tomcat o 7 isn't a possibility, and it wasn't crashing before this app was deployed so blaming the server isn't a viable solution either.

Could anybody give me an idea of what may be using these files or adding that `._` on them?

below is full traces log, it goes from deployment to Tomcat restart. {AppName} is war's name. There's no reference at all to our packages anywhere in stacktraces, it all happens Tomcat's code.

```
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive {AppName}.war
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-es.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.processTlds(StandardContext.java:4307)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1220)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-compiler-jdt.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-ja.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-factory-dbcp.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jsp-api.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-en.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-fr.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-resources.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-compiler.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._commons-el.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-factory.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._servlet-api.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:06:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-runtime.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:07:21 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/{AppName}]
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive {AppName}.war
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-es.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-compiler-jdt.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-ja.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-factory-dbcp.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jsp-api.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-en.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/i18n/._tomcat-i18n-fr.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-resources.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-compiler.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._commons-el.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._naming-factory.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._servlet-api.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
GRAVE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /var/tomcat/tomcat-5.5.25/common/lib/._jasper-runtime.jar in context /{AppName}
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
...
18/11/2013 11:12:15 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint processSocket
GRAVE: Unexpected error processing socket
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
18/11/2013 11:17:41 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8081
18/11/2013 11:17:42 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
18/11/2013 11:18:46 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
18/11/2013 11:18:46 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I accidently delete 'temp' direcrtory under Tomcat root directory and it poses this error message. Maybe you can check if temp exists or not. If yes, then check if the ownership of the account that starts Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to increase your shared memory settings when starting tomcat.
this can be a temp folder issue (think of no space, no permissions, as Scott did write)

Additionally it is possible that this is just too much ram you use:

Increase your Xmx and Xms values and you might want to update your heap settings aswell.

Ceck the SF search for "OOM tomcat" and you will find the rest of the things you need to learn.